# Why doesn’t an irregular or polygon shaped hole work like a pinhole camera when held close to the screen?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, camera

When a card with a hole of any shape is held close to the screen, the lighted area on screen is of the same shape as the hole. To make an image of light source, say Sun, the card has to be moved away from the screen to get an image- the focal length of the pinhole. Why does it not show the image in the first case? I want to understand the path of light rays for the two situations and the transition.

Images:
https://www.exploratorium.edu/sites/default/files/lightwalk/08.jpg

https://www.exploratorium.edu/sites/default/files/lightwalk/06.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If the image is smaller than the hole you observe just the shadow of your card.The light rays coming though are parallel for all practical purposes.